# TextBox с выравниванием по вертикали по середине

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить код ниже (c# winforms vs2010 net4.0), чтобы значение в ReadOnlyTextBox выравнивалось по вертикали по середине (ReadOnlyTextBox имеет свойство Multiline=true)?

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class ReadOnlyTextBox : TextBox
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool HideCaret(IntPtr hWnd);

    public ReadOnlyTextBox()
    {
        this.ReadOnly = true;
        this.BackColor = Color.White;
        this.GotFocus += TextBoxGotFocus;
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
    }

    private void TextBoxGotFocus(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        HideCaret(this.Handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Никак, стандартный `TextBox` так не умеет. `RichTextBox` может сделать выравнивание по центру горизонтально, но не вертикально, за счёт rtf-разметки. Можно попробовать скормить html в `Label`, но я не уверен, что стандартный `Label` его обработает, проверить сейчас не могу. Либо использовать что-то стороннее

Comment: Используйте WPF, там это делается очень просто

Answer (score 0):

Ответ неполный.

Можно попробовать ручную отрисовку текста.

Сразу после появления текстбокса выравнивание будет как нужно. Вот только при клике по текстбоксу почему-то меняется шрифт на моноширинный... Возможно, нужно установить какой-то стиль (но я не нашёл, какой).

```
public class ReadOnlyTextBox : TextBox
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool HideCaret(IntPtr hWnd);

    public ReadOnlyTextBox()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);

        ReadOnly = true;
        BackColor = Color.White;
        Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
    }

    protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        HideCaret(this.Handle);
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, Text, Font, e.ClipRectangle, ForeColor, BackColor,
            TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.WordBreak);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

Код внутри `OnPaint` можно заменить на следующий:

```
using (var brush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor))
using (var stringFormat = new StringFormat { LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center })
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, brush, e.ClipRectangle, stringFormat);
}
```

`TextRenderer` - это GDI. `DrawString` - это GDI+. Рендерят они слегка по-разному.

Примечание: внутри класса-наследника лучше использовать перегрузку методов (`override`) вместо подписки на события.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @olga - За что спасибо? Не работает же.

Comment: @olga если помогло - отметь галочкой что ответ правильный.